# Add a dropdown inside OnGUI function

Tags: unity-game-engine

I build a menu inside the OnGUI function like

```
GUILayout.Label("Singleplayer");
if(GUILayout.Button("Zombie"))
    ChangeScene("Zombie");
```

Is it possible to add a Dropdown programmatically like i create the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this in the editor - i.e. a custom Inspector or EditorWindow - then yes:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.DropdownButton.html

But if you're doing it in-game, you need to stop using the OnGUI method (it's not supported any more by Unity) and switch to using the new UnityUI (which isn't really "new" any more - it went live almost 5 years ago! :)). UnityUI has built-in drop-down functionality you create directly in the Editor:

https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown.html

and:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Dropdown.html

Comment: Thank you but i need it while playing (not in editor) to display a list of downloaded scene assets. Seems like i have no other choise then setting up another canvas and put it in there..

Comment: You shouldn't use `EditorGUILayout` inside `OnGUI()`; it doesn't work because `EditorGUILayout` automatically calculates the rects for the controls, whereas `OnGUI()` passes you a Rect in which you are required to use (and is affected by `GetPropertryHeight()`. You should be using the `EditorGUI` class instead. See [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html)